Not Updating MAUI Controls
Hi I am updating MAUI controls. But its not updating If Update Controls , Compatibility nuget package is not updating, and vice versa. What is the problem can any one help me.


I can reproduce this issue. To upgrade these two packages simultaneously to the latest version 8.0.21, you can try to specify $(MauiVersion) in your csproj file from:
<PackageReference Include=“Microsoft.Maui.Controls” Version=“$(MauiVersion)” />
<PackageReference Include=“Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility” Version=“$(MauiVersion)” />


To:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.21" />
</ItemGroup>

And then restart Visual Studio 2022 and rebuild the app. The NuGet Manager will show the desired version installed:

